# I am not being able to open software and update?

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I am using Ubuntu Mate. Iam unable to open `Software & Updates`, it simply doesn't pop up.

That is why I am not being able to install Skype and other software. I followed few similar type of problem from ask Ubuntu but I could not solve the problem.

I have one red circle on the right top of my screen.

Comment: Please include the screenshot of red circle, also make it clear whether you use Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am using UBUNTU 16.04.  I don't know how to paste image here. It is a red circle inside it there is a minus sign. If I click on it it shows: (1) A Problem occurred when checking for updates. (2) Show Updates (3) Show notifications (4) Preferences. If I click on anything it does not work.

Comment: There's image with landscape background when you are in [edit] mode of post, click it and the rest is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Anyway your problem seem to be related to broken package, please run `sudo apt-get -f install` on terminal, paste the output here then.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Now skype has installed but I am clicking on it and it is not opening.

Comment: Do the Software & Updates program able to open sucessfully now ?

Comment: No, Still It is not opening. Need more instruction. Thanks

Comment: Hi !  am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Please open up a terminal, run `software-properties-gtk` to launch Software & Updates, considering you're unable to open it I expect some error output— please paste them here.